# Cookie sets on Localhost but not on live server?

Tags: javascript, cookies

It's my first time dealing with cookies in JavaScript and the below script works fine on my local PC but when I upload it here: [example](http://www.keithdonegan.com/jquery/stylesheet-switcher-with-cookies/) it fails.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

              // Get Cookie 
              var getCookie = document.cookie;

              if(getCookie == "stylesheet=blue")
              {
                    $("[rel=stylesheet]").attr({href : "blue.css"});
              }
              else if(getCookie == "stylesheet=main")
              {
                    $("[rel=stylesheet]").attr({href : "main.css"});
              }

              // Set Stylsheet back to Main
              $('#reset').click(function()
              {
                    $("[rel=stylesheet]").attr({href : "main.css"});

                    var setCookie = document.cookie = "stylesheet=main";
              });   

              // Set Stylsheet Blue
              $('#blue').click(function()
              {
                   $("[rel=stylesheet]").attr({href : "blue.css"});

                   var setCookie = document.cookie = "stylesheet=blue";
              });
        });
```

Any ideas?

Comment: seems to work fine for me on firefox

Comment: @Geoff, What happens if you click blue and refresh the page?

Comment: i see what it is now, see my answer - your cookie has more in it then you think :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you are using google analytics, which also sets its own cookies. So, when reading document.cookie property, it will never have the value eg. "stylesheet=blue", because it will contain information on other cookies. Call

```
alert(document.cookie);
```

and check the value for yourself.

You should use a function for getting cookie value, for example

```
function getCookie(N){
   if(N=(new RegExp(';\\s*'+N+'=([^;]*)')).exec(';'+document.cookie+';'))
      return N[1]
}
```

or use [jQuery cookie plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie)

Answer (score 1):

When you get the cookie back, it isn't just the string "stylesheet=blue" but has other information in it as well.

For me the string I get back looks like this:

```
"stylesheet=blue; __utma=168444603.22445052401845424.1242318397.1242318397.1242318397.1; __utmb=168444603.5.10.1242318397; __utmc=168444603; __utmz=168444603.1242318397.1.1.utmcsr=stackoverflow.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/questions/864324/cookie-sets-on-localhost-but-not-on-live-server"
```

check that the string contains "stylesheet=blue" instead of checking equivalance.

**Edit**: See what @Rafael said.  I like the JQuery cookie plugin

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding an expiration date to the cookie so that it hard sets it?

```
document.cookie = "stylesheet=blue; expires=Thu, 5 May 2011 20:47:11 UTC; path=/"
```

This is a hard coded example, but you can set the datetime as needed.